# How can I create tmTheme file with existing json file?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, ide

I want to create tmTheme file with existing json file to integrate my theme to IDE. How can I do this? Is there any tool to generate tmTheme file with json settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

https://github.com/JetBrains/colorSchemeTool

Here is a tool which allows to build tmTheme file with json file.

1. Put the file to *vscThemes* folder
2. Run *convert.sh*

After that tmTheme *file* will be published into *tmThemes* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a npm module to do that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmtheme-to-json

Comment: But as I understand it converts tmTheme to json, I want to create tmTheme with json. By the way I couldn't build with "tmtheme-to-json" in terminal. It says;

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my.tmtheme'